# Error failed starting bonjour resolution

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, bonjour

When I use XCode to develop my iOS product, it crashes in my iOS device occasionally. It always happens when the program from the background to the front, and the XCode shows as crash reason:

> [Error] Failed starting Bonjour resolution.

I couldn't find how to solve it and it make me very depressed.Is there anybody to help me?

[image: Screenshot goes here]